# Python unable to recognize additional imports while using functions from my own custom package

Tags: python, function, package

My agenda intent is to slowly start to build more robust code, and I've now started to build my own modules.

This is my hierarchy

```
main.py            
custom_pkg
   __init__.py
   custom_functions.py
```

Above, the *__init__.py* file is empty. I've also successfully, from *main*, imported my own functions using the statement `from custom_pkg import custom_functions`.

Now, I believe the issue lies within the fact that one of the functions from *custom_functions* is dependent on a further import (in this case *os*), and when I try to call that function in my main script *main.py* with `custom_functions.foo()`, I get an error message that *os* is not defined. Normally, the *os* package norms perfectly fine when I simply import it in a script and run it, but in conjunction my own package it seems I have to take an additional step.

I've tried, with no success, to put an `import os` statement in my *main.py* file before called my functions. I've also tried putting the `import os` statement on the top of the *custom_functions.py* file, and even inside the *custom_functions.foo()* function, but again, with no success. It feels as though I am neglecting an important concept here.

Comment: do you have any file/module that you created with name os? Use `os.__file__` to check which file is getting used when you import os

Comment: Good suggestion, but I have not created any other file/module called os.

Comment: It is a little difficult to follow without code example. But, if i understood - you have to import os in every file where you are using it. You cannot import os in main and have the other imported modules automatically use it.

Comment: Did you import os in your custom_function.py?

Comment: Luv and Daniel, I suspected that too. And I tried putting import os in the top of the custom_functions.py, but it still didnt work.

Comment: I've also tried to put import os inside the function foo() defined in custom_functions.py. I can successfully import this function (foo) from main, but its when I run it that I end up with the error message "os is not defined".